# How to kill a daemon with its name gracefully?

Tags: process, kill

I usually kill a process with `killall`.

```
killall markdoc
```

But I am not sure if this command terminates the process gracefully.
Does this command achieve graceful termination? If it does not, how can I kill a process with its name gracefully?

Comment: Does your distribution has [tag:start-stop-daemon]?

Comment: I'm using *Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server x64*. What's that daemon?

Comment: It is a generic tool for starting/stopping daemons and managing related information, like pid files. It is present in Ubuntu, see [its man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your question is not clear, you talk about a daemon in the title, but in the body only talk about a generic process.

For a daemon there are specific means to stop it, for example in Debian you have

```
    service daemon-name stop
```

or

```
    /etc/init.d/daemon-name stop
```

Similar syntaxes exist for other initscript standards used in other distributions/OS.

To kill a non-daemon process, supposing it is in some way out of control, you can safely use `killall` or `pkill`, given that they use by default the `SIGTERM` (15) signal, and any decently written application should catch and gracefully exit on receiving this signal. Take into account that these utilities could kill more that one process, if there are many with the same name.

If that do not work, you can try `SIGINT` (2), then `SIGHUP` (1), and as a last resort `SIGKILL` (9). This last signal cannot be catched by the application, so that it cannot perform any clean-up. For this reason it should be avoided every time you can.

Both `pkill` and `killall` accept a signal parameter in the form `-NAME`, as in

```
pkill -INT process-name
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually my original question was about `markdoc serve &` and `svnserve -d`. I think it's a kind of daemon, but nothing was certain to me :)

Comment: `killall` is the killer!

Comment: Sometimes process can ignore `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT`, so there would be no way to stop it "gracefully", the only way out would be to send `SIGKILL`

Answer (score 3):

On BSD-like and other distros, you will often have scripts in /etc/rc.d/ that typically manages starting, restarting and stopping daemons in your system. To stop a daemon you would either call the scripts with the absolute path e.g.:

```
# /etc/rc.d/acpid stop
```

or use the command:

```
# rc.d stop acpid
```

I highly recommend to try out this script for showing your systems started and stopped daemons:

```
#!/bin/bash

chk_status(){
  target=$1
  if [[ $target != "functions" && $target !=  "functions.d" ]]
  then
    if [[ -f "/var/run/daemons/$target" ]]
     then
       stat="\e[1;32m[RUNNING]"
     else
       stat="\e[1;31m[STOPPED]"
     fi

    printf "$stat \t\e[1;34m$target\e[0;0m\n"
  fi
}

daemons=($(for daemon in /etc/rc.d/*; do echo "${daemon#\/etc\/rc.d\/}"; done))

if [[ $1 != "" ]]
then
 chk_status $1
else
 for d in "${daemons[@]}"; do
   chk_status $d
 done | sort
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `killproc` function available in `/etc/init.d/functions` script, source the file and use the function. Or use `pgrep` and `pkill` utilities to check whether they are working intendedly and then use them. Example:  `pkill -SIGTERM mysqld` would send the TERM kill signal to have mysqld perform a safe shutdown and flush the databases onto the disk, before getting killed.